# Trying to state that you "may not have a future in this position"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I'm currently doing work for one company on a trial basis and hence since I don't know 100% if I will be kept on or not at the end of the trial I have still been looking out for other positions.

Now, I am trying to write a cover letter stating something like..

I am currently working for one company but the work there is not ______ so I still am looking for other opportunities.

What word am I looking for here? Guaranteed and sustainable don't seem like the right word?

Comment: If you don't like the work, it could be "... the work there is not ***my cup of tea***..."

Comment: @Eilia I do like the work, it's just a means to tell the other prospective employer that I am currently working but I may not have a future in this company because of x...... but in a short and non-descriptive way.

Comment: "... the work there is not **definite/certain**..." ?

Comment: @Eilia That's a little better. I may have to use that if nothing else comes forward :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not [reliable](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=reliable&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on), from [rely](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=rely&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on):

> Reliable, a. Suitable or fit to be relied on; worthy of dependance or reliance; trustworthy. A reliable witness to the truth of the miracles." A. Norton.
>
> ---
>
> Rely: To rest on something, as the mind when satisfied of the veracity, integrity or ability of persons, or of the certainty of facts or of evidence; to have confidence in; to trust in; to depend; with on.

nor is it [dependable](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=dependable&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on).

> Dependable, a. That may be depended on; as dependable friendships

The definition of [depend](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=depend&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) highlights why:

> 3. To rely for support; to be conditioned or contingent; to be connected with anything, as a cause of existence, or as a necessary condition; -- followed by on or upon, formerly by of.
> 4. To trust; to rest with confidence; to rely; to confide; to be certain; -- with on or upon; as, we depend on the word or assurance of our friends; we depend on the mail at the usual hour.

You rely upon the wages you earn from an unstable job to support you and your lifestyle. I believe that's the point, right?

However instead of writing "not _____" I'd suggest using the prefix [un-](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=un-&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on), which also negates, as in [unreliable](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&word=unreliable&resource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on) or [undependable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/undependableresource=Webster%27s&quicksearch=on). This means instead of writing the sentence as you suggested you'd write something like:

> I am currently working for one company but the work there is unreliable so I am still looking for other opportunities.

This is purely stylistic preference though. The phrases "is not reliable" or "is not dependable" would work here too.

---

**References:**

[Webster's Revised Unabridged 1913](http://www.bibliomania.com/2/3/257/frameset.html) (Except as specified below)

[The American Dictionary of the English Language by Noah Webster](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/), first published in 1828. (Steady, rely)

American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition (Undependable link)

Answer (score 2):

"... the work there is not ***definite/certain/bonded/secured***..."

Comment: See the following answer from aparente001.  This is a good answer from Eilia but this DOES NOT belong in your letter.  You're cutting your own throat.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you find the perfect word or phrase, please don't put it in your cover letter.  The interview is the place to use it.

I believe the euphemism you need is **opportunity for advancement**.

> Interviewer: We are looking for someone who will not get bored and
>   move on after 10 or 12 months.
>
> You: One reason I applied for your position is that my current
>   position does not have any opportunities for advancement.  The other
>   reason is that it is such a good fit with my talents and interests. 
>   (And then you're off and running on that theme.)